# Width of labels in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using scientific workplace 5.5 and if write `\begin{thebibliography}{LongestLabel}` the bibliography still seems to use 99 instead of `LongestLabel`. Is there a way of getting aroung this issue?

Comment: That should work.  I suggest you provide an example showing the bad behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently SWP tries to find the longest label and ignores user input. Since I was using a label with a special character, this was the longest label according to SW, but when typeset it was not and hence the width became to small. To overcome this I wrote `\relax` after the longest label so that SWP would recognize this as the longest label.